# Cannot change input language in jTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Why can't I switch input language in jtextfield and `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`?
On my computer I can, but on other computer I can write only system locale language symbols.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> is not working in application, but it is working when app is not focus

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH); //tried it
System.setProperty("user.language", "en"); // and it

private void showPasswordWindow() {

    String pass = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter password", "Secure", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    if (pass == null)
        System.exit(0);
    if (!pass.contains("somepassword"))
        showPasswordWindow();
}
```

Not working (( password contain English symbols and I can't to enter password (only Russia symbols working)

JRE 8;
PS: I want to enter English symbols, but I can type only Russian symbols...**NOT WORKING ONLY DIALOG TEXTFIELDS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally...i did it O_O

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

solved the problem, but i can't understand why??..

p.s. without the code on my comp app working nice

Answer (score 0):

You should change the [Locale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

```
textField.getInputContext().selectInputMethod(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

**EDIT**

Maybe it's not the best option, but you can try override the default `DocumentFilter` for the `JtextField` and change the encoding:

```
class EnglishTextField extends JTextField {

    public EnglishTextField() {
        ((AbstractDocument)getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter(){
            @Override
            public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                    String text, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
                try {
                    //TODO change to your current encoding
                    byte[] bytes = text.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
                    fb.insertString(offset, new String(bytes, "UTF-8"), attr);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: is there way to set it global?
or i need to do it for all textfields?
and how to do it for JOptionPane.showInputDialog?

Comment: Yes. Use `Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);`

Comment: Not working, same problem - http://www.coderanch.com/t/559975/java/java/JOptionPane-showInputDialog-change-input-language

Comment: Try changing the encoding.

Comment: how to do it for Dialog textfield? showInputDialog();

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues here.

The first is entering the symbols. This isn't really a Java problem, so much as an issue with [installing a different language for the keyboard](http://www.conversationexchange.com/resources/keyboard-language.php).

The second issue is displaying foreign language symbols. You may need to use a UTF font to display characters that otherwise don't display right

Comment: i know how to change language on my pc, i can't change when application window is focusing