# How to input Japanese text into Java Swing component with IBus-Anthy

Tags: java, linux, swing, ubuntu

I'm trying to type Japanese characters with the IBus-Anthy Hiragana input method on Ubuntu into a JTextField. However, even when I have this method selected (and it works in other applications), my input just appears as Latin characters.

I can copy/paste Japanese text into the text field, and display Japanese characters in other Swing components with no problem, so I don't think it's an issue with fonts.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: This same issue also arises with Pinyin. I can type non-Latin characters such as Cyrillic just fine, but I seem to have trouble with anything that requires special composition.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551513/cannot-change-input-language-in-jtextfield)

Comment: @Madhan Afraid the problem still persists.